# How to break out from javascript some function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that to break out of `$.each()` we can use `return false`, though this thing is not working in case of `some()` function. Is there a solution for it?
Consider I have an array `myVar[]` of objects. A snippet of my code is:

```
myVar.some(function(value) {
    if(value.name == 'some name') {
        return false; // is not breaking loop
    }
});
```

Though if I use

```
$.each(myVar, function(key, value) {
    if(value.name == 'some name') {
        return false; // is breaking loop
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`some` is not jquery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). `some` will stop processing when it **matches an element, so returning `true`**

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array until it finds one where callback returns a **truthy value**

Comment: ok, I incorrectly asked it for jQuery, I should have said JavaScript, and so `return true` will work as per your explanation rather than `false`

Comment: Off topic: the `some` method is new to me, but what a terrible name.  "one" is not "some", yet it's returning if "at least one" - that's not "some" - who came up with that terrible name?  Did someone copyright the `any` keyword?

Comment: That what the [spec says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17) `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of `some` to use as `Polyfill` provided in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some is below -

```
Array.prototype.some = function(fun, thisArg) {
    'use strict';

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined');
    }

    if (typeof fun !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError();
    }

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };
```

If you look carefully, it iterates over the whole array if it doesn't find a match. Even if you return false from the callback function it doesn't break the iteration. Returning false implies that your current item is not a match.

To break it down further, if your callback function finds the matching value, it will return immediately. But if it returns false, it will simply continue to the next item on the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (i in t && fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you look into the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17) it also says the same thing.